# The Rate of Radial Increase with Respect to Tangential Velocity for a Constant Rate of Turning

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Assuming an object is rotating at a rate of $1 rads^{-1}$ and is travelling forward (relative to itself) at speed $V ms^{-1}$ (constant for any particular iteration). This will produce a circular path of varying radius dependant only on $V$ (see below).

[image: Path Diagram]

My question is this. Is the radial increase proportional to $V$ or by what differential equation can this behaviour be modelled by. From here, is it possible to calculate a new rate of turn $K$ such that $R$ is constant for any $V$?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What do you mean by rotation? About what? Are you just talking about uniform circular motion about the center of the circle?

Comment: rotation of the object around it's virtical axis (assuming we're looking down upon it) such that despite it always moving forward (relative to itself) it traces a circle relative to our external view.

Comment: Oh, so intrinsic rotation versus extrinsic rotation ... But I do not understand how that affects the global path relative to a fixed origin.

Comment: Yeah... Although having had a think myself I might have over complicated this, if we let $D = Distance$, T = Time$, V = Tangential Velocity$, $r = Radius$ and $R = Rate of Rotation$ I think you can do the following: $D=\pi r$, $T = D/V$, therefore $R = 2\pi/T = 2V/r$.

Comment: Right. But then there's no intrinsic rotation about an axis. It's just standard constant speed circular motion.

Comment: As for your point about the path, if the object is rotating at a constant speed and travelling at say $5ms^{-1}$ the radius will be smaller than at $10ms^{-1}. Won't it?

Comment: Sure. We're just doing $s=r\theta$, so $\Delta s/\Delta t = r\Delta\theta/\Delta t$.  If you fixed $\Delta\Theta/\Delta t$, then $\Delta s/\Delta t$ is proportional to $r$.

Comment: @TedShifrin ahh, true, hadn't thought about that... but could that be translated into the form described for the purpose of modelling this in a game engine where there is a physical rotating object, hence the question.

Comment: Yep... I seriously over complicated it then, thanks! Can tell it's been months since my A Levels finished... I've already forgotten most of circular motion.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I seriously over complicated this task. Essential this models simple circular motion so the following can be shown to be true.

There are two main ways to approach this. First, you could calculate the differential equation for the rate of change of rotation speed with respect to velocity to keep the radius constant, then solve this for the rotation speed. The second, and perhaps easier way is as follows:

The distance the particle has to travel is constant, assuming a circular path, this is equal to $2\pi r$, else, it is $(\theta/2\pi)2\pi r$.

Consequently, we can calculate the travel time of the object to be equal to the distance divided by its tangential velocity, giving $(\pi r)/V$.

Finally, the rate of turn is equal to $2\pi$ divided by the time the turn takes, which gives $R=2V\pi/ \pi r$ $\mathrm{rads}^{-1}$. Which cancels down to $R=2Vr \, \mathrm{rads}^{-1}$.

Thanks @TedShifrin for helping me with this and making me realise how much I had over complicated this.